# how to create a pipe model in vtk with repeatability

Tags: python, vtk

I created a pipe model by rotating a bunch of cylinders but I donno how to filter common part and ,I am running a for loop to create cylinders and rotating them on a circle.This has a problem that I need to set the position in loop ,I want to attach all cylinders to one polydata object and then use it
This is my code

```
import vtk
import math
import wx
# create a rendering window and renderer
ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renWin.AddRenderer(ren)

# create a renderwindowinteractor
iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)
i=0
sourc=[]
mapper=[]
actor=[]


for i in range(0,360):
    sourc.append(vtk.vtkCylinderSource())
    sourc[i].SetRadius(0.3)
    sourc[i].SetHeight(6)

    sourc[i].SetCenter(2*math.cos(i),0,2*math.sin(i))
    sourc[i].SetResolution(100.0)
    sourc[i].Update() 

    mapper.append(vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper())
    mapper[i].SetInput(sourc[i].GetOutput())

    actor.append(vtk.vtkActor())
    actor[i].SetMapper(mapper[i])
        #actor[i].SetPosition(0,2*math.cos(j),2*math.sin(j))
        #actor[i].RotateZ(j)
    actor[i].GetProperty().SetOpacity(1)

        #actor[i].SetPosition(2*cos(i),2*sin(i),0)
    ren.AddActor(actor[i])

    i=i+1
# create source
#
transform = vtk.vtkTransform()
transform.Translate(0.0, 0.0,0)

axes = vtk.vtkAxesActor()
#  The axes are positioned with a user transform
axes.SetUserTransform(transform)



ren.AddActor(axes)



# enable user interface interactor
iren.Initialize()
renWin.Render()
iren.Start()
```

Comment: can you be more concrete with what you want you do? what is your visualization, what do you want to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add several `PolyData` objects into one use the `vtkAppendPolyData`object:

```
import vtk

append = vtk.vtkAppendPolyData()

for i in range(0, 360):
    (...)
    append.SetInputData(sourc[i].GetOutput())

append.Update()
```

then you can add the actor and render outside of your loop.